# How to sort a list with streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'd like to sort a simple list. Example with `Integers`:

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(4, 2, 7, 1, 4);
numbers.stream().sorted((n1, n2) -> {
    System.out.println("comparing: " + n1 + " with " + n2);
    return Integer.compare(n1, n2);
});
```

Result: Nothing is printed! No sorting is applied.
Thus the sort method is not even executed. Why?

Sidenote: my intention is to modify the list directly (within an object), thus I'm trying to prevent creating a new list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sorted()` is not a terminal operation, so it doesn't execute the `Stream` pipeline.

You have to apply some terminal operation, such as `.collect(Collectors.toList())` in order for the sorting (as well as any other intermediary operations) to be performed.

```
List<Integer> sorted = numbers.stream().sorted((n1, n2) -> {
    System.out.println("comparing: " + n1 + " with " + n2);
    return Integer.compare(n1, n2);
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want to sort the original List without creating a new one, use `List`'s `sort` method :

```
numbers.sort((n1, n2) -> {
    System.out.println("comparing: " + n1 + " with " + n2);
    return Integer.compare(n1, n2);
});
```

Of course you don't really need to pass a `Comparator`, since you are using the natural `Integer` ordering, which will be used by default if you just write :

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(4, 2, 7, 1, 4);
numbers.sort (null);
System.out.println (numbers);
```

Output :

```
[1, 2, 4, 4, 7]
```

From `List`'s `sort` Javadoc :

> If the specified comparator is null then all elements in this list must implement the Comparable interface and the elements' natural ordering should be used.

Comment: What if I want to modify the stream that is sorted directly? Without creating a new list? Like  `obj.getMyList().stream.sorted(..)`? How can I directly resort the list within the object?

Comment: That's kind of the point of functional programming, to _not_ have side effects.

Comment: Ok I see, so I'd have to call the setter on the list after sorting. No better solution?

Comment: @membersound I'm not sure if it can be done, but you can run the sort method of `List` in order to sort the original List.

Comment: Oh, so I'm probably misusing `streams` here if inplace sorting was my intention?

Comment: @membersound probably

Comment: I personally don’t like the contract of using `null` for `Comparable` elements without any compile-time check for correctness. I prefer `numbers.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());`, the result is the same but the compiler will immediately shout if there is no natural order.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sort method directly on List
    `numbers.sort((n1,n2) -> n1.compareTo(n2));`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify your list, you could use the `Collections.sort(List)` method instead of using the stream.

Example:

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(4, 2, 7, 1, 4);
Collections.sort(numbers);
System.out.println(numbers);
```